# SQL Server 2012 Full Text Search match results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, freetext

I would like to know if there is a way to get the words that were matched from a full-text search using `FREETEXT`.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE FREETEXT(column_name, 'search term')
```

I'd like to be able to see which parts of the text in column_name triggered a match with 'search term' since `FREETEXT` returns records where the searched column are more than just the search term pattern matches as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017#freetextfreetexttable) in the `FREETEXT`/`FREETEXTTABLE` section.

I know that using `FREETEXTTABLE` can return the rank and key but I need to know which actual terms triggered a match if it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Disclaimer, I haven't done this -- I'm going from documentation.`  I'm not sure this gets you what you want, but you can see how the search is tokenized:
from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017#freetextfreetexttable)

> After you apply a given word breaker, thesaurus, and stoplist
>   combination in a query, you can see how Full-Text Search tokenizes the
>   results by using the sys.dm_fts_parser dynamic management view. For
>   more information, see [sys.dm_fts_parser (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-parser-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

I'm guessing if you want to know which part (token) caused the match -- you'll likely need to run the search on the individual tokens and compare the result sets to see which token or tokens (search term/s) caused the given match.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually moving in this direction as well. And it did work using `FORMSOF`. I was able to get the list of possible words and then check to see which of those terms exist in the tokenized list of the text of interest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `full text search` another way then use plenty of method few are written below

```
Select * from Table
Where Column_Name Contains('some thing')

Select * from Table
Where Column_Name exists ('some thing')

Select * from Table
Where Column_Name in ('some thing')

Select * from Table
Where Column_Name =(some) ('some thing')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try LIKE

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column_name like ('%search term%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need  [Split String](https://sqlhints.com/tag/split-delimited-string-in-sql/) function

Then you will to create one `Temporary table` which is permanent.

Like in my example StagingFreeText (define data type as per requirement)

```
create table StagingFreeText (col varchar(100) not null)
```

Then create `Full Text Index` on `StagingFreeText`

In the start of script always truncate table

```
Truncate table StagingFreeText
```

Then insert the result into `StagingFreeText`

```
 ;with CTE as
(
SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE FREETEXT(column_name, 'search term')
)
insert into StagingFreeText(col)
SELECT value 
FROM CTE 
cross apply(select value from dbo.split_string(column_name,' '))ca
```

Again apply search condition like above

```
SELECT * 
FROM StagingFreeText 
WHERE FREETEXT(col, 'search term')
```

**Note :** My script is not tested but idea is very much clear.

Or if you don't want to Create another Free Text index on `StagingFreeText` then you can split the `Search Term` in #temp table and join `StagingFreeText` with #temp table